# Recibo Undefined pero si se imprime la información por consola

Tags: javascript, reactjs, map

En un proyecto de React JS, estoy trabajando con la API de SkyScanner, puntualmente estoy intentando imprimir las diferentes monedas dentro de un select, como se ve en la siguiente imagen:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Utilizó la función map en el siguiente componente:

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Button, Container, Form } from "react-bootstrap";

const FormularioBusqueda = () => 
  const [arregloMonedas, setArregloMonedas] = useState([]);

  let consultarMonedaURL =
    "https://skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com/apiservices/reference/v1.0/currencies";

  useEffect(() => {
    consultarMoneda();
  }, []);

  const consultarMoneda = () => {
    fetch(consultarMonedaURL, {
      method: "GET",
      headers: {
        "x-rapidapi-key": "3a61d965efmsh763ab4a859eb191p1173b1jsn61d45064a77d",
        "x-rapidapi-host":
          "skyscanner-skyscanner-flight-search-v1.p.rapidapi.com",
      },
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((datos) => {
        console.log(datos.Currencies);
        setArregloMonedas([datos.Currencies]);
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        console.error(err);
      });
  };

  return (
    <Container>
      <Form className="mt-5">
        <section className="row d-flex justify-content-center">
          <div className="col-md-2 col-sm-12">
            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Destino" />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-2 col-sm-12">
            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Origen" />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-2 col-sm-12">
            <Form.Select aria-label="Default select example">
              {arregloMonedas &&
                arregloMonedas.map((moneda) => {
                  console.log("Moneda", moneda);
                  moneda.map((code) => {
                    console.log("code.Code", code.Code);
                    <option>{code.Code}</option>;
                  });
                })}
            </Form.Select>
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-2 col-sm-12">
            <Form.Control type="text" placeholder="Locale" />
          </div>
          <div className="col-md-2 col-sm-12">
            <Button className="w-100">Buscar</Button>
          </div>
        </section>
      </Form>
    </Container>
  );
};

export default FormularioBusqueda;
```

Llamé dos veces seguidas a la función map, ya que el JSON que solicito a la API, cuenta con un Object llamado "Currencies", dentro de éste hay más Objects, de los cuales extraigo la propiedad "Code". En la siguiente imagen está el archivo JSON:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cuando imprimo por consola la variable **code.Code**, puedo obtener todas las monedas:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que no entiendo es, por qué por consola se imprimen bien, pero cuando trato de generar los options del select no aparece nada.

Puse la función map en una variable, para ver qué info recibía, y es Undefined.

Comment: El método `map()` solo te creara un nuevo `array` ejecutando el **callback** a cada uno de los elemento `nuevoArray = arregloMonedas.map( (moneda) => { ...`, pero creo que lo estas usando de manera incorrecta. Tu lo usas como **bucle** con el fin de renderizar tus **options**. Tal vez deberías usar un `forEach` en su lugar

Comment: O prueba retornando el valor `return <option>{code.Code}</option>` veo que no tienes un **return**

Comment: Intenté ambas cosas, agregar el return o reemplazar el map por un forEach, pero el resultado sigue siendo el mismo: Undefined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se está usando un **block scope** en la función `callback` de `map`, por lo tanto se debe especificar explícitamente el `return`:

```
arregloMonedas && arregloMonedas.map((moneda) => {
                  console.log("Moneda", moneda);
                  return moneda.map((code) => {
                    console.log("code.Code", code.Code);
                    return <p>{code.Code}</p>;
                  });
                })
```

Con esta modificación debería funcionar.

---

#### Refactor

> Llamé dos veces seguidas a la función map, ya que el JSON que solicito a la API, cuenta con un Object llamado "Currencies", dentro de éste hay más Objects, de los cuales extraigo la propiedad "Code"

Se puede asignar el arreglo `datos.Currencies` directamente a la variable de estado `arregloMonedas`:

```
//en vez de crear un array de arrays
setArregloMonedas([datos.Currencies]);
//[[array de arrays]]
//lo asigno directamente al array
setArregloMonedas(datos.Currencies);
//[un solo array]
```

Luego, se puede construir el `select` con un solo arreglo, quedaría algo así:

```
arregloMonedas && arregloMonedas.map((moneda) => { 
   return <option>{moneda.Code}</option> 
})
```

Espero que esta respuesta sea de ayuda.

Comment: Muchas gracias hermano! Funcionó!

Comment: Ya casi lo tenías, solo era ese detalle, saludos

Answer (score 0):

Hola veo que estas llamando, arregloMonedas.map y a eso luego le haces moneda.map, no revise tu api pero si probe con otra que tiene una estructura similar en el JSON y me parece que en el segundo llamado deberías probar moneda.Currencies y de allí sacas el Code, como ejemplo:

arregloMonedas.map((moneda) => {
console.log(moneda.Currencies.map((code)=> item.Code))

ya que en el primer map obtienes todo y en el segundo vas al especifico,

y revisa si no te hace falta un "{" en la linea de la creación del componente:
const FormularioBusqueda = () =>

Comment: Hola John, gracias por responder. Intenté agregando Currencies pero me da error: "TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined". Tampoco está faltando alguna llave "{".

Answer (score 0):

Los métodos map generan una nueva array con lo que se retorna de la función que aplica. También el valor generado será una nueva array de arrays, quizás es mejor solo devolver una array. En este caso tu métodos map no tienen return prueba:

```
{arregloMonedas &&
       arregloMonedas.map((moneda) => { 
        return moneda.map((code) => {          
          return <option>{code.Code}</option>;
       });
    })}
```

Sin embargo, ese código al tener dos map devolvería un array de arrays que no creo que a React le hiciera gracia, para solo devolver un array de componentes, se me ocurre, seguro que hay mejores opcione:

```
const options = (arreglo) => {
  const opt = [];
  arreglo.forEach((moneda) => {   
    opt.push(...moneda.map((code) => {     
      return <option>{code.Code}</option>;
    }))
  })
  return opt;
}
...
{arregloMonedas && options(arregloMonedas)}
```